# Call MyBase keyword in derived classes

Tags: vb.net

I want to ask about is it correct when i do Override multiple times. However there are in fact three question i got on top of my mind and i do not want to create separated topics as it's all related. Thanks for all answers.

**1st question:**
Let's say i have one base class when contains overidable method and then all derived classes in hierarchy doing like this:

```
BaseClass1
Overidable SomeMethodX

BaseClass2:BaseClass1
Overides SomeMethodX

BaseClass3:BaseClass2
Overides SomeMethodX

BaseClass4:BaseClass3
Overides SomeMethodX
```

Is it above correct when i do override. like this?

**2nd question:**
Based on above example do i have to always put in every ovveride method call to MyBase.SomeMethodX or just when i want to?

**3rd question:**
Consider below example. Is there any diffrence when i call just `MyBase.SpecificTechnologyActions` or should i do `return MyBase.SpecificTechnologyActions` instead (and please to explain why).

BaseClass1

```
Protected Overridable Function SpecificTechnologyActions() As Boolean Implements ITechnologyOperation.SpecificTechnologyActions           
    Return True
End Function
```

BaseClass2 : BaseClass1

```
Protected Overrides Function SpecificTechnologyActions() As Boolean
    MyBase.SpecificTechnologyActions()
    If Not CheckCounters() Then Return False
    Return True
End Function
```

BaseClass3 : BaseClass2

```
Protected Overrides Function SpecificTechnologyActions() As Boolean
    MyBase.SpecificTechnologyActions()
    If Not CheckNetworkElementsCount() Then Return False
    If Not CheckCounters() Then Return False
    Return true
End Function
```

Comment: **1)** Define _"correct"_. You override the parent class's method, I don't see what could possibly be incorrect about that. -- **2)** Depends on what you want to do. Call `MyBase.SomeMethodX()` if you want the parent class's method's code to run as well, or don't if you **only** want the current class's code to run. -- **3)** `Return` exits the function, ignoring any code that comes after that. Again everything comes down to what you want to do, i.e.: Do you want the parent class's `SpecificTechnologyActions()` method to run as well as the current class's?

Comment: @VisualVincent Generally saying i read something, somwhere like : "it's good to return value of base method.." however i am not sure what was it all about. Is it something known by you?

Comment: *1)* There's nothing wrong with that pattern.  *2)* There are two general reasons to override a method.  One is to _augment_ the base class functionality, the other is to _replace_ it.  If you are augmenting, you should call the base class version.  *3)* Return values mean something.  The answer to your question depends on the return value's meaning. Your example with Boolean return values probably indicates success or failure.  In this case, return true only if both the base class method returns true, and your code succeeds.  Don't just ignore the base class return value.

Comment: If you don't have a link to the page you read that I can't say anything about it. Whether it is good or bad to return the base class's value really only depend on what _**you**_ want or need it to do.

Comment: @VisualVincent "somewhere" is a remarkably similar post from the same user a few hours ago on which Hans left a comment along those lines